# Swapping rows of double 2d array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a method in java that will allow me to swap the rows of a 2d array of the double type.  My code works perfectly when I use it on a 2d array of ints, but it doesn't work when applied to double.  Am I missing something fundamental about double data types? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
// swapRows
// double[][] Integer -> double[][]

public static double[][] swapRows(double[][] a, int i)
{
   double[] temp = a[i];

   for(; i < a.length - 1; i++)
      a[i] = a[i+1];

   a[a.length - 1] = temp;

   return a;

}
```

// version 2 with new 2d array

```
 public static double[][] swapRows(double[][] a, int i)
 {
   double[][] b = new double[a.length][a[0].length];

   double[] temp = a[i];

   for(int k = 0; k < i;k++)
      b[k] = a[k];

   for(; i < a.length - 1; i++)
      b[i] = a[i+1];

   b[b.length - 1] = temp;

   return b;

  }
```

// note that the rows don't just swap, the specified row i is sent to the bottom of the array, and every other row shifts up
// for the 2d array:

```
{ {3, 5, 6},
{2, 1, 1},
{9, 0, 4} }
```

// I expect that when i = 0, the method return the 2d array :

```
{ {2, 1, 1},
{9, 0, 4},
{3, 5, 6} }
```

// but instead I get:

```
{ {0.0, -29.999996, -38.571428},
{18.999997, 0.0, 0.999999},
{18.0, 29.999996, 36.0} }
```

// when I use int instead of double, I get the expected array

Comment: you should include the code for the array swap

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Well, of course they don't just swap: you're not swapping them. What's the problem?

Comment: There is a missing "i" : ` for(; i < a.length - 1; i++)` my bad, he is..

Comment: @xoxel. Not sure I agree with you. `i` is an input parameter.

Comment: @MadPhysicist woops ! true

Answer (score 1):

As the code is correct IMHO, the 2D array must be corrupt (*unlikely*, same `double[]` row object in two rows), or *much more likely* the fact that you are altering the passed array, and returning it too, might indicate some erroneous handling of the result.

```
double[][] a = ...
double[][] b = swapRows(a, i);
// a == b
```

---

***A version that is creates a copy that is changed:***

```
public static double[][] swapRows(double[][] a, int i) {
    double[][] result = new double[a.length][];
    for (int j = 0; j < a.lnength; ++j) {
        result[j] = Arrays.copyOf(a[j], a[j].length);
    }

    double[] temp = result[i];
    for(; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
        result[i] = result[i+1];
    }
    result[result.length - 1] = temp;
    return result;
}

double[][] a = { { 1.0, 2.0 }, { 3.0, 4.0 } };
double[][] b = swapRows(a, 0);
assert b[0][0] == 3.0 && b[0][1] == 4.0 && b[1][0] == 1.0 && b[1][1] == 2.0;
System.out.println("result = " + Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

Comment: I think you're right that it might be the array.  Because when I use the array { [ 7 12 6]; [8 2 0]; [2 1 0]} . I get the expected return except that all  values are negative where they should be positive.

Comment: And that the swapRows alters the passed parameter, `a`? Looks like a systematic error, like `double[][] b = negate(a);` (and now also `a` is negated) and such.

Comment: I added a second version that uses a new array so that the input has a different reference than the output.  However, I still get the same result.  Do you have any techniques for identifying where the systematic error is?

Comment: The error probably lays just at a different spot. I have added test code.

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the problem.  I had other test lines in my main function that were modifying the value of the array before it was passed into the swapRows method.  Thank you for you assistance.